# Automate Excel Row Grouping based off another worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook that has many sheets with the same roster of people on it. Some of them have left and we "group by" the ones who are no longer working here on the sheet. However, there are many tabs and it would be much easier to group outline one tab and have a macro essentially copy the outline to the rest of them.

Example:

John.
Joe.
Susie.
Claire.
Adam.

If I have five tabs, and on the first one Susie and Adam are grouped, what could I use to make it so Susie and Adam were grouped in the other tabs?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

My latest code idea that I've written in effort to solve this problem is as follows:

```
'DelSum
    With Sheet21

    'Resets Group By
    .Range("Position").ClearOutline

    'Groups Principals
    topRow = .Range("Position").Find(What:="Principal", LookIn:=xlValues, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True).Row
    bottomRow = .Range("Position").Find(What:="Principal", LookIn:=xlValues, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=True).Row
    topRow = topRow - 1

    Rows(topRow & ":" & bottomRow).Group

    End With

    'Groups those who do not work here
    For Each Cell In Sheet21.Range("lastMonth")
        lastRow = Cell.Row
        posRange = Sheet21.Range("B" & lastRow).Value
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(posRange, Sheet7.Range("A5:L" & Sheet7.Range("A5").End(xlDown).Row), 9) = 1 Then
                If Cell.Value = 0 Then
                    Cell.Rows.Group
                End If
        End If
        Next Cell
    End With
```

Sheet7 is the master list of employees, the 9th column is where I denote if they have left the practice (with a 1 meaning they left). posRange refers to their name which also shows up in the first column of Sheet7.

The issue with this script is a 1004 error on the VLookup formula (error 1004 unable to get the vlookup property). When I look at posRange it has a person's name, and I can clearly see their name in the destination range.

Comment: Please provide the code you have attempted to write to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Sheet (or "tab", as you say) called "Active/Inactive" with all listed roster folks in one column, and a second column where you flag them as "Active" or "Inactive".  Then, in every other sheet, insert a column with a vlookup to your new "Active/Inactive" sheet.  Then, as people are added to your roster they are added to this sheet.  Since all the columns look to this one sheet you only have to manage it in one place.

Your "grouping" can then be accomplished using the autofilter.